# onupdate='cascade' is not working in the column in a table in Flask

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

as I am not an expert on flask-sqlalchemy, this might seem to be very basic question.

I have two table i)project ii)project_users in postgres db

i)Project Table

```
class Project(BaseModel):

    __tablename__ = 'projects'
    id = Column(fields.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    uid = Column(fields.UID, nullable=False, unique=True)
    users = relationship("ProjectUser", lazy='select')
```

ii)Project_Users Table

```
class ProjectUser(BaseModel):

    __tablename__ = 'project_users'
    id = Column(fields.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    project = Column(fields.UID, ForeignKey(Project.uid), nullable=False)
```

NOW as we can see project field in PROJECT_USERS table is a foreign key and references from PROJECT table.

So, I want to **modify uid in the project table** but that gives foreign_key_violation error , so in order to solve that I have tried to **cascade** the foreign key in PROJECT_USERS Table using the following ways

i)In PROJECT_USERS table

```
project = Column(fields.UID, ForeignKey(Project.uid), nullable=False, onupdate=u'CASCADE)
```

ii)In PROJECT Table

```
users = relationship("ProjectUser", lazy='select', cascade="save-update)
```

I am still not able to solve  key violation error. **"sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation)"**

Can anyone please help and tell how can I correctly add cascade?

Thanks